# Html text colours heatmap lots of font tags (slow)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm currently writing an application that returns an array or [word, value] tuples. For example:

```
var data = 
[['Hello', 1]
['world', 1]
['how', 5]
['are', 9]
['you', 16]
['?', 1]]
```

I want to display the text word by word as a heatmap according to it's value. There can be many words/sentences that appear hot in a large text corpus leading to many font tags:

```
<font color="#{value}">{word}</font>
```

Example:

```
<font color="#111">hello</font>
<font color="#111">world</font>
<font color="#555">how</font>
<font color="#999">are</font> 
<font color="#FFF">you</font>
<font color="#111">?</font>
```

All of the tags create a huge DOM and this can cause the browser to become very slow. This can be seen when scrolling or interacting with the text.

Are there any alternatives that offer better performance? I need the text to be selectable so images won't suffice.

Comment: How many is "many words/sentences" ? Perhaps an SVG would provide an improvement.

Comment: **Don't use the <font> tag**. It's been deprecated for 20 years now and removed from HTML5 altogether.

Comment: Check this out. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: yes I am aware the the font tag is no longer supported however I can't see an alternative that can color each word individually. Gaby, I have considered SVG but I think I might run into the same issue with it being an XML based format. The text base could be several pages worth.

Comment: um... `<span style="color:#111">`

Comment: Also, if you have a fixed set of colors using classes *might* be faster (or it might not). Other than that the only option is to make the content smaller (split the text to multiple pages etc.)

Comment: As you suggested, I think I might have to consider paginating the text and limiting the number of classes (freezing, cold, medium, warm, hot, boiling) for example. Not perfect but it might be okay for this.

Comment: Actually it seems as though it doesn't make a huge amount of difference if you use classes or not, check my answer below for tests.

Answer (score 0):

I have created two tests in JS Fiddle to approximate what your question was describing, one using classes and the other programmatically assigning an inline colour to the text:

**Inline based array of values:**
http://jsfiddle.net/h6kd5zu4/

```
["Lorem", 0],
["ipsum", 1],
["dolor", 2],
...

let colourList = [
  ["000"],
  ["111"],
  ["222"],
  ...

let theColor = colourList[randomWords[i][1]];
let listItem = "<p style='color:#" + theColor + "'>" + randomWords[i][0] + "</p>";
```

**Class based array of values:**
http://jsfiddle.net/cjgwuk2q/

```
["Lorem","zero"],
["ipsum","one"],
["dolor","two"],
...

let listItem = "<p class="+ randomWords[i][1] +">" + randomWords[i][0] + "</p>";

<p class="zero">Lorem</p>

.zero {
  color: #000;
}
```

#### Results

For an array 10000 items long the difference is fairly tiny:

- **Inline colours:** 34ms
- **CSS classes:** 20ms

You could get some savings by pre-assigning each item with a CSS class but it's very minimal.

Considering that this is a list of 10000 items and it's loading in around 30ms, how many items are you talking about and also how are you actually adding the items to the DOM?

I have created a third test which writes each item to the DOM rather than building a 'virtual' set of items first and then appending the whole lot in one go. I am wondering if you are rewriting the DOM on each addition, if so this takes considerably longer at around 5 seconds just for 2000 items:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6mnefLb/

#### Possible solutions

If the above hasn't brought any help to your situation you could try one of the following:

1. Build the view backend so there isn't as much heavy DOM work on the client side
2. Split the list into blocks of results, either lazyload the results as the user scrolls/interacts or put them into a multiple pages/paginated sections

Comment: Great answer Alex but the problem really happens when trying to scroll etc.

Comment: Could you add the specifics to your question? Otherwise no way to know these details.

Comment: Yes sure, sorry.